# How to update time to match with defined average time between two datetime, in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, mariadb

I have a query that give me two datetime columns and the time between the two datetime.
I want to update one of the 2 datetime so that the average time between these 2 datetime will be equal to a defined average time.

```
    DATETIME_1       |   DATETIME_2       | time_between1and2(in minutes)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-11-03 12:28:42  |2021-11-03 12:25:31 | -3.1833  (<0 incorrect)
xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx  |xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx | -x.xxxx  (<0 incorrect)
xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx  |xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx | -x.xxxx  (<0 incorrect)
xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx  |xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx | x.xxxx   (>0 so correct)
```

Average time between DATETIME_1 and DATETIME_2 : - 2.51 minutes (for exemple)

Average time wanted : 2.12 minutes (for exemple)

So I need to update all incorrect time(time between the two datetime) by update one of the two datetime so that the average time(average time between the two datetime) match with the average time wanted.

I don't see how to do it. Sql or pseudo code with example table names might help me.

Comment: Sounds like a complicated way to solve the problem of having some incorrect datetime values. If you can define a SELECT query which returns the records which need to be adjusted and there is some consistent logic to how they should be adjusted, then you can just write an UPDATE statement to do this. If you can provide some sample data and expected output, people will be better able to help you too.

Comment: I have update my post, my problem is better described, I leave aside the view.

Comment: So what is preventing you from writing an `UPDATE` statement to make the necessary changes to the incorrect rows? What have you tried and what went wrong when you tried it. You might want to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you want to get more good answers from people.

Comment: Sorry, actually I don't have a specific error, it's rather that I don't see how to change the datetime so that the average of the time data between the 2 datetime equals a correct average which could be precisely defined (I don't know yet but for example: 2.5 minutes)
For example sql pseudo-code with table names that are not necessarily mine could help me. To be precise it's just changing one of 2 datetime columns so that the average time between these 2 is equal to a defined average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very vague, as discussed in the comments, but here's an example of how to do an update like the one I think you are describing:

```
declare @sampleData table
(
    id int,
    Date1 datetime,
    Date2 datetime
)

insert into @sampleData values
(1, '2021-11-03 10:01:00.000', '2021-11-03 10:02:00.000'),
(2, '2021-11-03 10:03:00.000', '2021-11-03 10:06:00.000'),
(3, '2021-11-03 10:08:00.000', '2021-11-03 10:09:00.000'),
(4, '2021-11-03 10:16:00.000', '2021-11-03 10:16:30.000'),
(5, '2021-11-03 10:32:00.000', '2021-11-03 10:35:00.000'),
(6, '2021-11-03 10:48:00.000', '2021-11-03 10:51:00.000')

select * from @sampleData

update @sampleData
set Date2 = dateadd(minute,2,Date1)
where datediff(minute,Date1,Date2) > 2

select * from @sampleData
```

Output:

[image: Output Results]

So, we update all of the records where the difference between dates is greater than 2 minutes and make the difference exactly two minutes instead.

This assumes that `Date1` is always earlier than `Date2`, although if this is not necessarily the case, there are ways to handle this too.

Edit: If as per your comment, you want to add 2 minutes to the existing time instead of setting it to 2 minutes exactly, then you can do:

```
update @sampleData
set Date2 = dateadd(minute,2+datediff(minute(Date1,Date2),Date1)
where datediff(minute,Date1,Date2) > 2
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it will help me. I am not very good at SQL and databases. Also, I have completely revised my post, so that it is much clearer, at least I hope it is :)

Comment: No worries - if the answer was helpful or solved your problem, please consider upvoting and accepting it.

Comment: I would think you should be able to figure that out from what I've given, but I'll drop an edit now if you can't.